# Android app Http requests communication over USB OTG with Arduino

Tags: java, android, http, arduino, usb

My Android App is communicating with Arduino HTTP server over WiFi. I need to change communication way from WiFi to USB OTG. I'm **beginner** in this area so my question is: When I change to USB OTG can I still use http request from Android app to Arduino server ? It will be working as before or is it not possible ?

Answer (score 2):

surely it won't be working out-of-the-box, USB isn't IP protocol, thus HTTP isn't applicable to this transport. use `UsbDeviceConnection` and `UsbInterface`, still you can use currenlty used data structure, only transport will change. some DOCs about USB in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb)

Comment: Thanks, ok If I understood correctly http request/response code logic on Android and http server on Arduino will be useless when I switch to usb otg and I need to implement different logic to send and response data.